# How send 64 bit integer over COM interface from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, 64-bit, midl

I have a 64 C++ COM server and a C# COM client. Now I want to pass a structure from the server to the client that holds a 64 bit integer.

I use the keyword "hyper" for the MIDL compiler and can see that the field is `_int64` in C++ and `long` in C#.

But if I set the value `0x0000000000000001` in C++ I get `0x0000000100000000` in C#.

How can I correct this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a question of alignment. My 64 bit number was not aligned in the structure.
Added a #pragma pack(4) before the structure definition.
Then it worked.